# How should you check whats in stock on an order?

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

**My issue:**
I am trying to make an system which checks if orders has their items in stock.
I am using 3 databases for this.

```
Products Database:
Product ID  Name    Disposable
ABC123      Chair   15
AFG999      Table   1
CHO555      Sofa    15

Order Details:
ID    Customer ID    Date
1555  123            2016-04-12
2666  333            2016-04-13

Order Details: 
ProductID    Quantity    OrderID
ABC123       5           1555
CHO555       2           2666
AFG999       2           2666
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that it iterates through the ordered products and checks if they are in stock.
Also imagine that some orders will have over 20 products on them, how would I do this most efficiently?

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to solve it by iterating through the order details database and splitting them by a comma "," in php, like so:

```
$getorderdetails = mysqli_query($connect, 
"SELECT corders.id, GROUP_CONCAT(corderdetails.productid) as productid,
 GROUP_CONCAT(corderdetails.quantity) AS quantity
        FROM corders, corderdetails
        WHERE corders.id = corderdetails.orderid
        GROUP BY corders.id
        ORDER BY corders.id");
```

This outputs something like this:

```
Order ID    Ordered Products    Ordered Quantity
2666        CHO555,AFG999       2,2
```

So I tried splitting it up in arrays and searching the database one by on but I never really got it to work and I was wondering if someone else may share their solution?

Comment: I think you are better off returning the quantity information on the first request to the db - the one that gets the product information. This way you won't need to make extra connections to the db.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What is the expected output?..

Comment: @sagi What I want to achieve is a system that returns which orders are shipable.

Comment: And how do we know which orders are shipable? guess? @user2750279

Comment: @sagi compare the ordered quantity to the disposable quantity?

Comment: And ? if quantity < disposable then to return ?

Comment: @sagi Obviously, but I don't know how to get to that stage.